# C# Marshalling Structure with Strings to C Library

Tags: c#, android, c, pinvoke, marshalling

I am writing a C library that I must interact with from Unity3D (C#) and am running into an issue with writing one of my PInvoke calls.

I have the following c struct

```
typedef struct TestStruct
{
    const char* Method;
    const char* Url;
} TestStruct;
```

And C function signature

```
__declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl TestMethod(TestStruct* args)
{
    // Do stuff with Method and URL
}
```

In C# I've created my struct like so

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct TestStruct
{
    public string Method;
    public string Url;
}
```

And PInvoke signature like so

```
[DllImport("Test", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern void TestMethod(TestStruct args);
```

Now when I run this in the Unity editor on Win64 it works just fine. But when I deploy it to my android device (Nexus 6 which I believe is a 32 bit ARM architecture) the Method and Url properties are null in my test struct when they get to the C lib.

Strangely enough, if I change my function signatures to take the raw arguments avoiding the struct entirely, it works just fine.

```
__declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl TestMethod(const char* Method, const char* Url)
{
    // Do stuff with Method and URL
}
```

and

```
[DllImport("Test", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern void TestMethod(string method, string url);
```

Works just fine. Does anyone have any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: `(TestStruct args)` should be `(ref TestStruct args)`...

Comment: Wow. Thank you. That was spot on. Could you post this as an answer so I can accept it as the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl TestMethod(TestStruct* args)
```

is equivalent to:

```
[DllImport("Test", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern void TestMethod(ref TestStruct args);
```

or `out TestStruct`, depending on who will write to the `TestStruct`.

Important: if the `string`s are passed C->C#, then C# shouldn't modify them (or .NET will try to free them with the wrong deallocator and bad things will happen). If you use `out TestStruct` the C-side will have to deallocate the returned `const char*` I'll have to say I don't know how exactly (because you are using Unity and not .NET under Windows, so the thing gets a little more hairy)